# Динамически создаваемый объект и обращение к методу

Tags: java

Добрый день, начал изучать java совсем недавно, появился вопрос. В php мы можем вызвать метод таким образом:

```
$name = 'productController';
$action = 'run';
$controller = new $name;
$controller->$action();
```

Пробовал сделать что-то подобное, не получается.
Возможен подобный вызов в java или тут всё строго и такой свободы не ждать? :)

Comment: Не понятно :)))

Comment: @СергейГрушин вполне себе понятно. Динамически создаваемый объект и обращение к методу

Comment: @DaVASrK пока на ум приходит только рефлексия (Reflection)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за направление, почитаю и попробую через рефлексию сделать

Comment: Заголовок вопроса подправить бы, чтобы понятней было, о чем речь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать способ под названием рефлексия (Reflection)

`Reflection`  в *Java* используется для просмотра информации о классах, интерфейсах, методах, полях, конструкторах, аннотациях во время выполнения java программ.
При этом знать названия исследуемых элементов заранее не обязательно.

Все классы для работы с `reflection` расположены в пакете `java.lang.reflect`.

С помощью рефлексии можно

- Получить информацию о модификаторах класса, полях, методах, константах, конструкторах и суперклассах.
- Вызвать метод объекта по имени.
- Выяснить, какие методы принадлежат реализуемому интерфейсу/интерфейсам.
  Создать экземпляр класса, причем имя класса неизвестно до момента выполнения программы.
- Получить и установить значение поля объекта по имени.
- Узнать/определить класс объекта
- прочее

Пример:

```
    MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // <--- это класс, который будем просматривать

    Class c = obj.getClass(); // Получение объекта типа Class
    Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods(); // возвращаем все методы класса не зависимо от типа доступа

    for (Method method : methods) {
        System.out.println("Имя: " + method.getName());
        System.out.println("Возвращаемый тип: " + method.getReturnType().getName());

        Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes(); // берем параметры метода
        System.out.print("Типы параметров: ");

        for (Class paramType : paramTypes) {
            System.out.print(" " + paramType.getName());
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------");
    }

    // Пример получения конкретного метода по имени
    Method method1 = с.getMethod("simple");
    // Вызвать метод с помощью invoke - передать туда только объект
    String simple = (String)method1.invoke(c);
```

Если мы не знаем имя класса на момент компиляции, но знаем во время выполнения приложения, то можно использовать метод `forName()`, чтобы получить объект `Class`.

```
Class obj = Class.forName("com.test.classes.MyClass");
```

---

Также вместо

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // <--- это класс, который будем просматривать
Class c = obj.getClass(); // Получение объекта типа Class
```

Можно писать:

```
Class obj = MyClass.class;
```

Т.е. не нужно создавать экземпляр класса (который может вызвать конструктор и провернуть неизвестные манипуляции), а мы уже знаем в момент компиляции  какого типа он будет.

Comment: В принципе ничего сложного, спасибо, буду разбираться теперь на практике :)

Comment: @DaVASrK изучив что-то, всегда становится это легким)) Удачи

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите динамически, вызывать методы или создать объекты основываясь на названии.

В `java` для этих целей есть несколько интрументов [`reflection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), [`method handlers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html).

Написал небольшой пример:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String methodName = "greeter";
    reflectionInvoker(methodName, Solution.class);
    methodHandlerInvoker(methodName,Solution.class);
  }

  private static void reflectionInvoker(String methodName, Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
    Method method = clazz.getMethod(methodName);
    method.invoke(null);
  }

  private static void methodHandlerInvoker(String methodName,Class<?>clazz) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandle methodHandle= MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(clazz,methodName, MethodType.methodType(void.class));
    methodHandle.invoke();
  }

  public static void greeter() {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

Comment: Достаточно было отредактировать свой старый ответ и восстановить его, а не плодить еще один. На будущее...

Comment: Именно то, что надо. Читаю рефлексию в яве и попробую сделать, спасибо!

Comment: @DaVASrK лучше methodhandlers используйте, они быстрее

Comment: @Artem Konovalov хорошо, спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё строго :) Ява - язык со строгой типизацией. Каждая переменная относится к определенному типу. Тип переменной ограничивает множество значений, которые можно присваивать такой переменной.  Если это объектный тип (т. е. любой, кроме примитивных, типа `int` или `double`), то у класса, к которому относится эта переменная, чётко определен набор членов (полей и методов), и только к этим членам переменной можно обращаться. Некоторую гибкость даёт наследование с возможностью использовать интерфейсы в сочетании с приведением типов и `reflection` (возможность узнавать всё что нужно про класс объекта в том случае, если мы имеем объект неизвестного типа).